# How to blackhole an external address in an exim relay server without rewriting?

Tags: exim, rewrite

I have a scenario where email is sent through my outbound relay with a do-not-reply 'To:' recipient (the actual recipients are BCCd).

Example of what these emails look like:

```
From: <from@mydomain.com>
To: <do-not-reply@mydomain.com>
Bcc: <actualrecipient@gmail.com>
Subject: foo
```

The BCCd recipients should still receive mail, but I'd like to blackhole the attempt to deliver to the do-not-reply recipient, which exists on an external domain. Note that `mydomain.com` is not hosted by this exim server for incoming mail - this mail server is strictly for relaying.

I attempted a rewrite approach but that would modify the 'To' address that the BCC recipient sees, which looks confusing. Since the do-not-reply recipient is not going to a locally hosted domain, a traditional aliases setup to blackhole the address doesn't work, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a redirect router.  In the routers section of your Exim config file, add the following router:

```
blackhole_do_not_reply:
    driver = redirect
    local_parts = do-not-reply
    domains = mydomain.com
    data = :blackhole:
```